# NameError: name 'sys' is not defined appears with buildozer

Tags: python, android, runtime-error, sys, buildozer

I tried to made an Android app with the Package tapo-plug, kivy and buildozer, but the app crashes directly after opening it. I never did something like this before. This is the Error-message send by my phone:

```
02-04 16:32:53.560 23072 23113 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
02-04 16:32:53.561 23072 23113 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/test/ServerManagementApp/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 19, in <module>
02-04 16:32:53.561 23072 23113 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/test/ServerManagementApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Vexludus/arm64-v8a/tapo_plug/tapoPlugApi.py", line 11, in <module>
02-04 16:32:53.561 23072 23113 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/test/ServerManagementApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Vexludus/arm64-v8a/tapo_plug/tapoEncryption.py", line 7, in <module>
02-04 16:32:53.561 23072 23113 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/test/ServerManagementApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Vexludus/arm64-v8a/Crypto/PublicKey/RSA.py", line 38, in <module>
02-04 16:32:53.561 23072 23113 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/test/ServerManagementApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Vexludus/arm64-v8a/Crypto/IO/PKCS8.py", line 44, in <module>
02-04 16:32:53.561 23072 23113 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/test/ServerManagementApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Vexludus/arm64-v8a/Crypto/IO/_PBES.py", line 43, in <module>
02-04 16:32:53.561 23072 23113 I python  :    File "/home/daniel/test/ServerManagementApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/Vexludus/arm64-v8a/Crypto/Hash/MD5.py", line 45, in <module>
02-04 16:32:53.561 23072 23113 I python  :  NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
02-04 16:32:53.561 23072 23113 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I already set tapo-plug,Crypto,PyCryptodome,pyjwkest,pycrypto as requirements.

This is my first time doing something like this.

This is the script-part the error occurs in:

```
from Crypto.Util.py3compat import *
```

from Crypto.Util._raw_api import (load_pycryptodome_raw_lib,
VoidPointer, SmartPointer,
create_string_buffer,
get_raw_buffer, c_size_t,
c_uint8_ptr)

_raw_md5_lib = load_pycryptodome_raw_lib("Crypto.Hash._MD5",
"""
#define MD5_DIGEST_SIZE 16

```
                    int MD5_init(void **shaState);
                    int MD5_destroy(void *shaState);
                    int MD5_update(void *hs,
                                      const uint8_t *buf,
                                      size_t len);
                    int MD5_digest(const void *shaState,
                                      uint8_t digest[MD5_DIGEST_SIZE]);
                    int MD5_copy(const void *src, void *dst);

                    int MD5_pbkdf2_hmac_assist(const void *inner,
                                        const void *outer,
                                        const uint8_t first_digest[MD5_DIGEST_SIZE],
                                        uint8_t final_digest[MD5_DIGEST_SIZE],
                                        size_t iterations);
                    """)
```

Comment: Did you try to use `sys` without first `import sys`?

Comment: Show us the `MD5.py` file.

Comment: the error occurs only when running on a android device in the a package Script. Therefore it is not a Script I wrote myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to guess what cause your issue without minimal reproductable sample. I made simple Kivy project, it works without issues under Windows and Android.

buildozer.spec requirements:

```
requirements = python3,kivy,pycryptodome,pkcs7,Crypto,tapo-plug,requests,urllib3,charset_normalizer,chardet,idna
```

Sample code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from Crypto.Util.py3compat import *  # pip install pycryptodome
from Crypto.Hash.MD5 import *
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from tapo_plug import tapoPlugApi  # pip install tapo-plug

class app(App):

    device = {
        "tapoIp": "127.0.0.1",
        "tapoEmail": "dummy@dummy.com",
        "tapoPassword": "dummy"
    }

    def build(self):
        return BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')

    def on_start(self):
        self.root.add_widget(Label(text=str(b('test'))))
        self.root.add_widget(Label(text=MD5Hash(b'test').hexdigest()))
        try:
            self.root.add_widget(Label(text=tapoPlugApi.getDeviceInfo(self.device)))
        except Exception as e:
            self.root.add_widget(Label(text=str(e)))
            pass

app().run()
```

Comment: I basically use tapo-plug to control a power outlet. This works fine on Windows. But on Android the error message above occurs. Line 19 is the line where I import the package `from tapo_plug import tapoPlugApi` that causes the error. I never use Cypto directly.

Comment: I edited code above. Requirements were changed. This one is running both on Windows and Adnroid. I have no TP-Link Tapo device but I suppose it will work.

Comment: Thank so so much for your help! I do not know where the problem was, but after clearing the buildozer it works again